# Drools .NET 3.0 - List<> C#

Tags: drools

I am using Drools. Net 3.0, but I can not use list structures as exists in Drools java version. 
example:

```
//Code Drools - This code does not work in Drools. NET
rule 'ListC#' 
when
   Object1 ($list: listObjects)
   Object2 (date> = '01/01/1992') from $list 
then
  mensagens.add ("132"); 
end


//C# Code
class Object1
{
  public List < Object2> listObjects {get; sets;}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix?

Answer (score 0):

Drools in java is already in version 6, so the .NET port is really outdated by now. I wouldn't expect the new rule syntax to work with the old .NET port.. you can try to find out the drools 3.0 docs out there.. but there is no guarantee that it will work.